# Finite Semigroups property

Tags: finite-semigroups

**Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements of a finite semigroup. Show that if
$abb = b$, then $bab = b$.**

Now I did this: $abb = b$, so $bab = abbab$. But $abb = b$, so $bab = b$.
I know in semigroups this doesn't work like in strings.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $S$ is finite.

Comment: Consider the maps $x\mapsto bx$ and $x\mapsto ax$ on the (finite) set $bS$.

Comment: @bof: don't you need to look at those maps on $bS \cup \{b\}$  to handle the case when the semigroup doesn't have a unit? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RobArthan No, I was missing something when I wrote that slapdash comment. Yeah, $bS\cup\{b\}$.

Comment: @bof: S is finite so there exists an idempotent. Now how should I use this?

Comment: The idea is to show that bof's two maps are inverse to one another.

Comment: @RobArthan can you write the whole solution? I am a new bee in this field.

Comment: I have written up an answer below, leaving some facts about functions on finite sets for you to think about, if you don't know them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the finite semigroup and assume $a, b \in S$ are such that $ab^2 = b$.  Define functions $f$ and $g$ on $S$ by $f(s) = as$
and $g(s) = bs$ and consider the set $bS \cup \{b\}$ (where $bS = \{ bs \mid s \in S\}$).
If we restrict $g$ to $bS \cup \{b\}$ and restrict $f$ to the range of $g$, we have.
\begin{align*}
g &: bS \cup \{b\} \to b^2S \cup \{b^2\},  \\
f &: b^2S \cup \{b^2\} \to ab^2S \cup \{ab^2\} = bS \cup \{b\}
\end{align*}
given our assumption that $ab^2 = b$, which also implies that,
for any $x \in bS \cup \{b\}$, $f(g(x)) = abx = x$, i.e., the composite $f \circ g$ is the identity function on $bS \cup \{b\}$. This implies that $\#(b^2S \cup \{b^2\}) \ge \#(bS \cup \{b\})$ (by fact 1 below). But $b^2S \cup \{b^2\} \subseteq bS \cup \{b\}$, so, as both sets are finite, we must have $b^2S \cup \{b^2\} = bS \cup \{b\}$. I.e., we have:
\begin{align*}
g &: bS \cup \{b\} \to bS \cup \{b\},  \\
f &: bS \cup \{b\} \to bS \cup \{b\}
\end{align*}
But, as  $bS \cup \{b\}$ is finite and $f \circ g$ is the identity on $bS \cup \{b\}$, $g \circ f$ is also the identity on $bS \cup \{b\}$ (by fact 2 below), giving us that:
$$
bab = g(f(b)) = b 
$$

which was what we wanted.

We have used two facts about functions involving finite sets $X$ and $Y$:

1. If $f : Y \to X$, $g : X \to Y$ and $f \circ g$ is the identity, then $\#Y \ge \#X$ (i.e., $Y$ has at least as many elements as $X$).
2. If $f : X \to X$, $g : X \to X$ and $f \circ g$ is the identity, then $g \circ f$ is also the identity on $X$.

(With a suitable interpretation of $\#X$ and $\#Y$, fact 1 is also true for infinite $X$ and $Y$, but we only need it for finite $X$ and $Y$ here. Fact 2 is not true for infinite $X$.)

Comment: Since a finite semigroup can be embedded in a finite semigroup with a unit, we could assume "without loss of generality" that $S$ has a unit, but there seems to be no real point to doing that.

Comment: @bof: thanks. That's a good point. I was trying to keep it as simple as possible.